# Prove that the union of open domain, its reflection, and a part of its boundary is open and connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

In my homework assignment I have to prove a variation of the Schwarz reflection principle.

Suppose $U$ is a open and connected subset of the upper half plane $\{z|Im(z)>0\}$ and there is an open interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}\cap\partial U$

Define $D=U\cup I \cup U^{\ast}$ , where $U^{\ast}=\{ \bar{z} | z \in U \}$ is the reflection of $U$.

> ... Moreover, suppose a function $f:U\cup I \to \mathbb{C}$ such that f is holomorphic on U, continuous on $U\cup I$ and $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in I$.
> Prove that a certain $g$ defined on $D$ is holomorphic...

The instructor also asks to prove that the set D, defined above is open and connected.

For **connectness** I used the fact that if $A$ is a connected subset of the space $E$ and $B$ is such that $A \subset B \subset \bar{A}$ then $B$ is connected.

But I really got stuck on **openess**..

Actually **I believe that I could provide a counter example.** i.e For the set $U= \{z|Im(z)>0\} \setminus \{\frac{i}{n} | n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ we have that $0\in D$ but there no open ball $D(0,r)$ contained in $D$

Comment: You are correct. As stated, this is false. An additional - though lesser - issue is that $I$ must be an open interval, not just any interval. Counter-examples for closed $I$ are almost trivial to construct.